# Server / client echo python on amazon ec2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, client-server, echo, serversocket

I want to make my EC2 instance as a server that listens to my local machine which is a client. I run the server.py on the instance and it runs and waiting for the client but on the client side, I received this error

> "Traceback (most recent call last): File "client.py", line 18, in
>   
>       client_socket.connect(ADDR) File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py",
>   line 228, in meth return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) socket.error:
>   [Errno 60] Operation timed out"

here is my code for both side:
Client

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

"""
a simple client
"""

import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 50000
BUFF = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
running = 1

#creates a client side socket and connect
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)

#listens for incoming requests
while running:
    data = raw_input('> ')
    if not data: break          
    client_socket.send(data)    #sends data to server
    data = client_socket.recv(BUFF) #received echoed data from server
    if not data: break
    print data

client_socket.close()
```

Server

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

"""
a simple echo-server
"""

import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 50000
BUFF = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
running = 1

#creates a server side socket and bind the socket to the host and port
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(ADDR)
server_socket.listen(2) # can keep 2 clients waiting while serving current client

#listens for incoming requests
while running:
    print 'waiting for connection...'
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    print '...connected from:', addr

    #client receives data and echoes it back 
    while running:
        data = client_socket.recv(BUFF)
        if not data: break  #stops when client doesn't send data
        client_socket.send(data) #echoes data back to client
    client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

Comment: you probably need your server host to be `'0.0.0.0'` which indicates to open all network interfaces instead of just localhost.... then your client needs to connect to the public ip address of your server, also you need to configure aws router rules to allow connections from outside

Comment: The remote host is not reached : Operation timed out . Have you a firewall ? try netstat or ss command for see if your echo server is correctly listenning on the ip 127.0.0.1 and the good port 50000. You must see your opened port. If you are behind NAT show the @Joran Beasley answer.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thank you so much I tried that and it's worked!